# JavaScript in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, dom-events

What's the reason why some JavaScript functions won't work in Google Chrome but works fine in Mozilla Firefox?

Like this..

**HTML code:**
...

```
onkeyup="calculateTotal(this.value)" 
onclick="clickclear(this, '0')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'0')" value="0"
```

**JS code:**

```
function calculateTotal(price, quantity, cnt) {  
    if(quantity != ""){  
        var totalAmt = parseInt(document.getElementById('total['+cnt+']').value);  
        totalAmt = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);

        document.getElementById('total['+cnt+']').value = totalAmt;
        document.getElementById('indicator').value++;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('total['+cnt+']').value = 0;
        document.getElementById('indicator').value--;

    }
}
```

**And already included this:**
jquery1.4.2.js

Comment: Could you plz provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo case?

Comment: chrome does have a javascript console (ctrl+shift+j). what does it say?

Comment: if you use jquery (which has the $ function), why do you spell out document.getElementById ?

Comment: Holy god @Ghommey, never seen jsfiddle before.  This is incredible

Comment: +1 @George Mauer for duplicating my reaction on finding jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling the function

```
calculateTotal(this.value)
```

but your function is:

```
function calculateTotal(price, quantity, cnt)
```

I don't know why this DOES work in Firefox (I'm assuming they automatically supplied parameters or something), but your two functions do not match up.

Comment: No, it's actually 

onkeyup="calculateTotal(<?php echo $row_item['item_price']; ?>, this.value, <?php echo $row_item['item_id'];?>)"

Comment: I just simplified it and I forgot to simplify the function. Actually, it's just for posting purposes that's why I removed some parameters just to show you guys the flow. It really works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

From the html 4 spec:

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

I would therefore replace your use of square brackets in ids before trying anything else.